# The change of php 5.2 to 5.6 modifies the characteristics of the opening and closing script

Tags: php

The opening of the scripts change

The closure of the scripts changes  ?>   to  ...--?>

The scripts are not executed

I searched the web possible causes, but I have not found anything.

Please, I ask help

Example:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $codigo_isef =  md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $codigo_isef  = trim($codigo_isef); 
?>
```

to

```
... <!--?
    session_start();
    $codigo_isef =  md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $codigo_isef  = trim($codigo_isef); 
...--?>
```

Let me explain:

I open with ""

The browser does not process the code and change the characters "...

Comment: Does changing `<?` to `<?php` work? If so then you need to enable short tags.

Comment: Both examples looks the same.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? your first code example is using the correct way to open and close php script.